# An asymptotic formula for a sum involving powers of floor functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\theta \geq 0$ and consider the sum $$\sum_{n \leq x} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor^{-\theta}.$$.

I have seen the claim that there is a constant $c(\theta)$ (depending on $\theta$!) such that this sum equals $$c(\theta)x+O(1),$$ where the implicit constants inside of the $O$ sign are independent of $\theta.$  Why is this true?

This is from an exercise in a book on Number Theory, and in the first part of the exercise, one was asked to prove the identity
$$\sum_{n \leq x} f(n) G(x/n) = \sum_{m \leq x} (G(m)-G(m-1))F(x/m)$$ where $F$ is the summatory function of an arithmetic function $f$ and $G$ the summatory function of some arithmetic function $g.$ This is probably relevant, but I do not see why.

Comment: Even without theta, most of the summands are 0 or 1.  With theta positive, the rest are between 0 and 1. If you are having trouble seeing this part, you should ask this on math.stackexchange.  Gerhard "The Equations Will Cost Extra" Paseman, 2019.08.15.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where have you seen this claim?

Comment: @GerhardPaseman It is obvious to me that most of the summands are between $0$ and $1$. Does this observation make the answer straightforward?

Comment: @HarryRichman It is from the book ”A course in analytic number theory” by Marius Overholt.

Comment: I can easily see that this sum looks as follows: for $n$ less than or equal to $x$ but strictly larger than $x/2,$ the summands are $1.$ For $x/3< n \leq x/2$ they are $2^{-\theta}$ and so on. But I am having trouble using this to get anywhere

Comment: So this suggests the answer should involve generalized harmonic numbers in some way. How is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: To me, it answers the question of why it is true that the O(1) does not depend on theta, because the "shape" of the sum (and thus a bound on the error) does not depend on theta. You can get a better error that depends on theta, but it is unclear whether this is worth the effort.  Gerhard "And The Equation Needs Fixing" Paseman, 2019.08.15.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Sorry if I am misunderstanding, but does this approach lead to an expression for $c(\theta)?$ Or why the leading term must be of this form?

Comment: It seems your question was about independence. Is your question really about the value of c(theta)? Gerhard "Perhaps I Do Not Understand" Paseman, 2019.08.15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function
$f(x) = \sum_{1\leq n \leq x} \lfloor \frac x n \rfloor ^{-\theta} $
can be expressed as
$$f(x) = \sum_k k^{-\theta} \cdot\#\{n : \lfloor \frac x n \rfloor = k\}$$
$$ = \sum_k k^{-\theta} \left(\lfloor \frac x k\rfloor - \lfloor \frac x {k+1}\rfloor \right)$$
$$ = \sum_k k^{-\theta}\left( \frac{x}{k^2+k} + O(1)\right)$$
so  the constant 
$c(\theta)= \displaystyle\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{k^{-\theta}}{k^2 + k}$.
Here  the implied error is bounded by
$\sum_{ k\leq x} 2k^{-\theta}$.

To get a better bound on the error term, we can regroup terms
$$f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor - \sum_{k\geq2} ((k-1)^{-\theta}-k^{-\theta})\lfloor \frac{x}{k} \rfloor$$
so the error from ignoring the ''floor'' signs is
$$ |c(\theta)x - f(x)| = \left| (x-\lfloor x\rfloor) - \sum_{k\geq2} ((k-1)^{-\theta}-k^{-\theta})\left( \frac{x}{k} - \lfloor \frac{x}{k}\rfloor\right) \right|$$
$$\leq 1 + \sum_{k \geq 2}((k-1)^{-\theta}-k^{-\theta}) = 2.$$